# How to Upload a ScreenShot Image to Server using http multipart FormData without using base64 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, http-post, screenshot, form-data

I want to upload screenshot image to server using Multipart FormData.
But in my code i save screenshot in download folder and this image i want to upload to server. but this this give me length error how can i solved this please help me on this i stuck in this error till 4 to 5 days.
ERROR IS(" [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 65894 bytes written while expected 436. [‰PNG   ")

Take screenshot of particular widget code

```
File? imgFile;
  Future<Uint8List?> _capturePngAndroid(int i) async {

    setState(() {
      downloaded = false;
    });
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
      print('inside');
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);

      ByteData? byteData;
      byteData = (await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png));

      var pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
      File imgFile = File('');
      Directory directory;
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
          directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
          String newPath = "";
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
          for (int i = 1; i < paths.length; i++) {
            String folder = paths[i];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/" + folder;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          newPath = newPath + "/download/banner/custom";

          directory = Directory(newPath);
          print('direcyg$directory');
          print(pngBytes);

          if (!await directory.exists()) {
            await directory.create(recursive: true);
          }
          if (await directory.exists()) {
            //var FileName = "Custom"+"${i++}"+"$duration"+".png";
            var FileName =
                "Custom_" + "${i++}"+"_" + "$convertedDate" + ".png";
            Save.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
            print("Save.path" + Save.path);
            imgFile = File('${directory.path}/$FileName');
            print("imgFile" + imgFile.path);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
          directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        downloaded = true;
      });
      imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
      Save = File(imgFile.path);
      print('Save $imgFile');
      uploadImage(Save);
      setState(() {
        isLimitCharacter = false;
        downloaded = true;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return DownloadImageScreen_custom(imgFile);
          },
        ));

        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'File Downloaded ',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.0);


        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: imgFile.path,
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.0);
      });

      return pngBytes;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This code for upload screen shot image to server using form data(Note Don't use base 64)

```
uploadImage(File imagePath) async {
    var request =
        http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(CustomDownloadImage));
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var tokens = prefs.getString("token") ?? '';
    print('tokens$tokens');
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $tokens';

    //add text fields
    request.fields["media_type"] = "image";

    //create multipart using filepath, string or bytes
    print("request-----" + request.fields.toString());
    // if(imageFile!=null) {
    var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("documents", imagePath.path);

    //add multipart to request
    request.files.add(pic);
    //}

    print("image_path----------------" + imagePath.path);

    print("request" + request.toString());
    var response = await request.send();
    //Get the response from the server
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    print(responseString);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("--------------------inside3---------------");
      return true;
    } else {
      print("--------------------inside3 Not---------------");
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you have to "save screenshot in download folder"? cannot you upload `pngBytes` directly?

Comment: @pskink i DONT UPLOAD PNGbytes .I upload this  (Save = File(imgFile.path);) in upload function uploadImage(Save);

Comment: If you use Dio Package, you can use Dio FormData to send the whole file without needing to convert to base64.

Comment: @ Karmrul Hasan Jony i dont want to convert this image image in base 64

Comment: @pskink yes this images save in download folder

Comment: @pskink so i try you suggestion than it work it or not save pngBytes

Comment: @pskink  I try using MultipartFile.fromBytes but its not working.

Comment: @pskink yes it snot receive any data , BUT I UPLOAD USING GALLERY PICKER TO UPLOAD IMAGE ITS WORKING

Comment: @pskink yes its working code for if i upload image to picking up in folder

Comment: @pskink but its not working with screenshot

Comment: @psKink status Code=>500
I/flutter (17206): Header=>{connection: close, access-control-allow-headers: *, cache-control: no-cache, private, transfer-encoding: chunked, x-ratelimit-limit: 60, date: Thu, 17 Feb 2022 10:39:29 GMT, access-control-allow-origin: *, vary: Authorization, access-control-allow-methods: *, x-ratelimit-remaining: 59, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)}

Comment: @pskink can you modify that code

Comment: in your code most likely you need `await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);` - but it is **NOT** the way you should do if you dont need to write your png image - instead you should use `MultipartFile.fromBytes` - thats all - no need to create any folders, no need to write anything anywhere

Comment: @pskink the code requirement is download screenshot image to save local storage and also upload image to server

Comment: i asked that in my first comment here - '''do you have to "save screenshot in download folder"?'''

Comment: @pskink yes your are right you ask the question on first comment ,

Comment: so did `await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);` help in any way?

Comment: @pskink await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes); is return as file

Comment: Any one known how to resolve this kind of issue.....